# how to synchronize or merge dataframe with json data based on timestamp

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, merge

there are many examples out there on how to merge two pandas dataframe but my Problem is that I have two kind of data. data1 is a csv data that I read it with pandas and turn it to dataframe and the other data2 is in json format.

here is an example of the json data:

```
[{'timestamp': 1572430625231, 'url': 'brakePressure', 'value': 10},
 {'timestamp': 1572430625275, 'url': 'lateralAcceleration', 'value': 120},
 {'timestamp': 1572430625290, 'url': 'longitudinalAcceleration', 'value': 110},
 {'timestamp': 1572430625299, 'url': 'acceleratorPosition', 'value': 1230},
 {'timestamp': 1572430625310, 'url': 'currentTorque', 'value': 10}]
```

as you can see every feature value is inside a dictionary with a timestamp. the problem is if I convert this to a dataframe the rows would be a timestamp, url and value but I don't want that, I want that my columns (features) would be brakePressure, lateralAcceleration etc.. and in every column there are all values that correspond to that feature and that are inside this json.

my Goal is to merge the two datasets based on timestamp. this is so hard because here in the json I have a timestamp assosiated with every single feature value, on the contrary in the csv data I have a timestamp that correspond to a row (that mean n feature value and not a single one). I tried so hard to do this but no chance, so I thought maybe I can search which is the closest timestamp and then replace a single value at a time, here is my try:

```
def sync_vehicle_gps_data(dataset=vehicle_data, gps_data=gps_data):
    vehicle = dataset.copy()
    gps = gps_data.copy()
    d = {}

    for json in vehicle:

        timestamp, feature, val = json.values()
        index = abs(gps['timestamp'] - timestamp).idxmin()
        print("closest value index = ", index)
        gps.at[index, feature] = val

    return gps
```

the vehicle_data are the json data and the gps_data is a pandas DataFrame, as you can see I search throught the whole dataset which timestamp is the closest to the single feature timestamp and then I update that specific value but this didn't work well for me. I ended up having messed up data. Is there any way to do this in python ? I can also use any other libraries if there is one so I'm not restricted to pandas.

the expected output is that I can append those values in the json above to the existing dataframe so that means in this example that a new columns 'brakePressure', 'lateralAcceleraiton' etc.. would be added and the value of each feature(as it is in the json above, yes they are zeros but it's only an example) would be put in the row where the timestamp of that row is the nearest to the timestamp of the timestamp key of each feature in the json above. I know it is a very complex problem, it's not easy to explain but I hope you understand what I mean. 
here is an example: let's say this is the gps data

```
      timestamp        X      Y     Z 
      1572430510880  595.00  179.00 -60.00
      1572430510890   -0.23   -0.09   0.01
      1572430510900   -0.11   -0.02   0.04
      1572430510910   -1.96   -5.19  -6.10
```

I want this output ( I ll show this only for one feature):

```
      timestamp        X      Y        Z    brakePressure
      1572430510880  595.00  179.00 -60.00   10
      1572430510890   -0.23   -0.09   0.01   nan
      1572430510900   -0.11   -0.02   0.04   nan
      1572430510910   -1.96   -5.19  -6.10   nan
```

the value of the brakePressure feature in the dictionary was put in the first row because the closest gps timestamp to the timestamp of the brakePressure in the dictionary above is also in the first row. Basically I want to do that same thing for all the features in the json, I want to synchronize all those feature values with the gps data

Comment: Can you post an example of the desired output?

Comment: @naive I made an update. I can show a desired output because I don't have one. I didn't achieve to implement it. I hope you ll understand what I mean from the edit that I just made

Comment: You can try pivot tables.

Comment: @naive I edited the question and showed one example of how the data should be.

Answer (score 1):

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html

You can create 0's and 1's as column values:

```
import json

json_data = [{}, ]
df1 = pd.read_json(json.dumps(json_data))
```

which gives

```
                timestamp                       url  value
0 2019-10-30 10:17:05.231             brakePressure     10
1 2019-10-30 10:17:05.275       lateralAcceleration    120
2 2019-10-30 10:17:05.290  longitudinalAcceleration    110
3 2019-10-30 10:17:05.299       acceleratorPosition   1230
4 2019-10-30 10:17:05.310             currentTorque     10
```

And, then

```
ready_to_join_df = pd.get_dummies(df1, prefix="", prefix_sep="")
```

which results in:

```
                timestamp  value  acceleratorPosition  brakePressure  currentTorque  lateralAcceleration  longitudinalAcceleration
0 2019-10-30 10:17:05.231     10                    0              1              0                    0                         0
1 2019-10-30 10:17:05.275    120                    0              0              0                    1                         0
2 2019-10-30 10:17:05.290    110                    0              0              0                    0                         1
3 2019-10-30 10:17:05.299   1230                    1              0              0                    0                         0
4 2019-10-30 10:17:05.310     10                    0              0              1                    0                         0
```

And now you can join two dataframes on key timestamp.

Comment: the problem is when I read_json with pandas I get 3 columns (correspond to every dictionary keys) but I want the dictionary url value to be the column name. did you get what I mean? I think you missunderstood the problem. take a look back at how my JSON looks like. I can't convert it to dataframe using pd.read_json that will mess things up. It would be great if I find a way to convert it to dataframe but I don't know how since every feature have a different timestamp, I can't stack feature values in one row and give them the same timestamp value because they have different timestamps

Comment: did you run `pd.get_dummies(...` , i.e. the last line of instruction? And is the resulting dataframe in the answer what you want right before joining?

Comment: your code will give a dataframe having 3 columns as a result (timestamp column, url column and a value column) but what I want to do is a whole different thing. I want every column to get dictionary value of the url key that I have in the json

Comment: my code will give you a dataframe NOT with 3 columns but all unique `urls` as columns. If this is not what you are looking for then probably the question doesn't explain the correct requirement.

Comment: thanks you are right sorry! I didn't thought this would happen. Ok and how can I join them now?

Comment: Here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Comment: after trying it I think it will not work because the values of all the features would be a 0 or 1 and every feature is not getting the value that is specified in the json

Comment: how can I efficiently replace the ones with the real value of the feature?